# Field revision_default must be updated

Tags: 8

After installing 8.4, updated step by step to 8.5.3, now I have in Status Report the following error: Field revision_default must be updated at several entity types, Node, Media, etc.
Checking the database, I have that field in the tables *_field_data and *_field_revision but not in the tables *_revision, though apparently it should be there.

drush entity_updates lists these error but does not fix them.

Searching several hours I did not find any solution. We have a lot of content and media so uninstall and install again is not an acceptable solution.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you run drush updb? system_update_8500() I think should fix that. drush entity-updates should never be necessary for drupal core/contributed modules

Comment: Yes, I tried it, it did not help.

Comment: How did it not help? did system_update_8500() run? did it return an error? Is drush updb reporting any updates that can't be run/don't go away? Have you tried update.php instead? You could also try to manuall execute that function with drush ev or so.

Comment: system_update_8501() I meant

Comment: There is nothing like system_update_8500(). In Google the only relevant search result for system_update_8500 is this page :-) I suppose you meant system_update_8501.
Unfortunately I don't know where to find whether that update ran. But at the moment drush updb says there is nothing tu update.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2951279#comment-12590544 for a related issue

Comment: The main issue was that for some unknown reason Drupal thought, the updates have been applied, although they haven't, 
I solved it by some hacky way, useing the code of system_update_8501() by some minor changes so that it was applied even if the system thought it should not.
Thank you, your help was useful!

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your database by using the drush commands :

```
drush updb -y
```

and

```
drush entities-update
```

If you dont have drush, you can use the /update.php page.
Regards,

Comment: Thanks, but I am not a fool, of course I tried to run database update and it did not help.

Comment: update.php is not capable of doing it either.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs because of a missing *(`revision_default`)* column in revision tables.

[image]

You can see in the above example the `node_revision` table is having `revision_default` column. Also you can see in block_content_revision, media_revision etc..
I was able to fix those issues when the column was added manually using drush then run the db updates.

Based on the error you get, need to run a db query. Can do that either directly or using `drush sql-query` command. If issue is with the `block_content_revision` table.

Run the following commands,

- Run SQL query command (*Run this command only if you get error for `block_content_revision` table)*

  ```
  drush sql-query "ALTER TABLE block_content_revision ADD COLUMN revision_default tinyint(5) AFTER revision_log"
  ```
- Then run `drush updb`
- Then `drush entup`